# Cannot Find build.gradle in Gluon Mobile Project

Tags: javafx, build.gradle, gluon-mobile

I was following the wonderfully detailed answer by @JoséPereda to this question: [How to testing Gluon app on iOS Simulator or Real Device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55950698/how-to-testing-gluon-app-on-ios-simulator-or-real-device). All was going well, but, looking at my Gluon project now, I don't know if I even have a build.gradle file. I seem to only have a pom.xml and nbactions.xml file. In fact, I cannot find any files or anything that says "gradle" in my Gluon project.

Comment: That answer was for the old EOL javafxports plugin, that has been superseded by the gluonfx plugin. See https://docs.gluonhq.com. It only describes the Maven plugin. But you can still use Gradle, though, see https://github.com/gluonhq/gluonfx-gradle-plugin

Comment: Ok, thanks @JoséPereda. I will use the information in that doc for testing the app on my phone. However, it doesn't explain how to upload to app stores. I have both the Android and Apple developer licenses. Is there a tutorial for doing that?

Comment: The doc covers how to sign your apps for the stores. You can find a nice tutorial for deploying here: https://foojay.io/today/creating-mobile-apps-with-javafx-part-3/

Comment: That is perfect! Thanks!